# Kivy: SoundLoader and loading multiple files, but not 'double-load'

Tags: python, audio, loading, kivy

I want to load multiple soundfiles (*.ogg) in kivy via the SoundLoader module. The files are from 300kB to 700kB big.

What happens is: The first couple files get loaded, then it skips the remaining files.

Is there a better (and maybe faster) way to load the files? Is it possible to 'link' an already loaded file to another Button instance, without copying it (or compromising it's text)?

Here's the code in question:

```
    #Getting filenames:

    for line in rawsongs:
        if ',' in line:
            items = line.split(', ')

            #Creating instances of Buttons, which control (play and stop)
            #the soundfiles:

            btn = AudioButton(
            text=(items[1]+' - '+items[2]), font_size=50, 
            sound = SoundLoader.load(items[2]+'.ogg'), 
            size_hint_y = None, height = 240, group = 'audio')

            #adding the Button to the Layout:
            grid.add_widget(btn)
        else:
            pass
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some IRC with the guys from #kivy, I got suggested to use the kivy - intern "cache manager"
[Cache Manager docs @ kivy.org](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.cache.html)
so the updated code is like this:

```
    #NEW: Registering the Cache

    Cache.register('songcache', timeout = 100)

    #Getting filenames:

    for line in rawsongs:
        if ',' in line:
            items = line.split(', ')

            #NEW: Check if the file is already cached:

            if Cache.get('songcache', items[2]) == None:

                #Setting up the button:

                btn = AudioButton(
                    text=(items[1]+' - '+items[2]), font_size=50, 
                    sound = SoundLoader.load(items[2]+'.ogg'), 
                    size_hint_y = None, height = 240, group = 'metro')

                #NEW: Adding the instance of the soundfile to the cache:

                Cache.append('songcache', items[2], btn.sound)

                grid.add_widget(btn)
            else:
                btn = AudioButton(
                    text=(items[1]+' - '+items[2]), font_size=50, 

                    #NEW: Linking the previously Cached instance with the new Button

                    sound = Cache.get('songcache', items[2]), 
                    size_hint_y = None, height = 240, group = 'metro')
                grid.add_widget(btn)           
        else:
            pass
```

So thanks to the guys from #kivy for helping!